# add rows from textbox in insert select command sql c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, insert-into, selectcommand

I am creating a web app in which i am using insert into select command

for which i have taken a stored procedure which looks like this

```
alter PROCEDURE profinalinstexpensesonid      
(                    
@from varchar(5000),                    
@to varchar(5000),                    
@trainer varchar(5000),      
@sonvinid varchar(5000),  
@button varchar(5000),
@bill_id varchar(5000)               
)                
AS                    
BEGIN      
if(@button='allselect')  
begin  
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount)    
select                     
instructoreexpense.sonvinid,    
sonvininsert.trainer,                   
convert(varchar,sonvininsert.date,105) as date ,                    
sonvininsert.brandname,                    
substring(sonvininsert.zone,1,1)as zone,                    
sonvininsert.location,                    
sonvininsert.area,                    
companysonvinunitvenue.venuename,                  
sonvininsert.venue,                    
sonvininsert.instructore,                                
instructoreexpense.amount      
from                     
instructoreexpense                     
left outer join sonvininsert on                     
sonvininsert.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid and                     
sonvininsert.status='0'                      
left outer join finalinstructoreexpense on                     
finalinstructoreexpense.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid                      
left outer join companysonvinunitvenue on                     
companysonvinunitvenue.id=sonvininsert.comsonvinid      
where                     
sonvininsert.sonvinid not in(select sonvinid from listinvoice)    
and    
sonvininsert.date                     
between convert(datetime,@from,105) and                     
convert(datetime,@to,105) and                     
sonvininsert.trainer=(select empname from trainerdetails where trid=@trainer)      
and instructoreexpense.sonvinid NOT IN (      
            SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER)      
            FROM SplitString(@sonvinid, ',')      
      )      
order by instructoreexpense.sonvinid 


end  
end
```

now this is working absolutely fine, now on this line

```
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount)
```

i want to add bill_id

and i will get my bill_id from a textbox in my program

so i want to change this line into something like this

```
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount,bill_id=@bill_id)
```

but i am gettig the error of

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure profinalinstexpensesonid, Line
>   14 Incorrect syntax near '='.

what i need to do,

i am getting bill_id from my textbox,

is there any other options???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your statement. You are currently doing this:

```
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount,bill_id=@bill_id)
```

Where it should be something like this:

```
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount,bill_id)
select                     
instructoreexpense.sonvinid,    
sonvininsert.trainer,                   
convert(varchar,sonvininsert.date,105) as date ,                    
sonvininsert.brandname,                    
substring(sonvininsert.zone,1,1)as zone,                    
sonvininsert.location,                    
sonvininsert.area,                    
companysonvinunitvenue.venuename,                  
sonvininsert.venue,                    
sonvininsert.instructore,                                
instructoreexpense.amount,
@bill_id
from                     
instructoreexpense                     
left outer join sonvininsert on                     
sonvininsert.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid and                     
sonvininsert.status='0'                      
left outer join finalinstructoreexpense on                     
finalinstructoreexpense.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid                      
left outer join companysonvinunitvenue on                     
companysonvinunitvenue.id=sonvininsert.comsonvinid      
where                     
sonvininsert.sonvinid not in(select sonvinid from listinvoice)    
and    
sonvininsert.date                     
between convert(datetime,@from,105) and                     
convert(datetime,@to,105) and                     
sonvininsert.trainer=(select empname from trainerdetails where trid=@trainer)      
and instructoreexpense.sonvinid NOT IN (      
            SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER)      
            FROM SplitString(@sonvinid, ',')      
      )      
order by instructoreexpense.sonvinid
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `INSERT` statement:

```
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,
location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount,bill_id=@bill_id)
```

You haven't finished the statement.  You would typically format it like this:

```
INSERT INTO (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (@Val1, @Val2, @Val3)
```

You would first list the columns for which you want to provide values in the first group and then list the values themselves in the second group after the keyword `VALUES`).

In yours, you appear to be listing the columns you want to insert with the exception of the last one, where you're trying to also assign a value somehow.  You need something like this:

```
insert into listinvoice(sonvinid,tid,date,brandname,zone,
location,area,venuename,venue,instructore,amount,bill_id)
VALUES (@sonvinid, ..., @bill_id)
```

Obviously you'd replace the ellipsis with your actual parameters.